# Which message brokers support one to one mapping between a key value and the consumer

Tags: architecture, message-queue, messagebroker, system-design

I am currently trying to choose a message queue in my backend system and for a use case I would need to do the following

- Producer services will publish messages that involve a field named foo
- I want all messages with same foo value to end up in the same consumer service all the time. Each consumer uses a single queue, so there is a 1-1 mapping between foo values and consumers

I am not sure which message broker would allow this out of the box.

I have tried to implement this in application code by using hashing in producer, `hash(foo)` and choosing the queue `topic/hash(foo)%N` for publishing. However, making consumers subscribe to topics they correspond to has some challanges: first, consumers need to know their id, which one is it, 1st, 2nd, Nth? In the case some consumers die this is another problem that makes consumer subscribe to wrong topics.

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly is your question?

Comment: I believe any MQ library will work here really.

Pub/Sub pattern on kafka/rabbitmq/zeromq (if you doing it on a local setup like it is kinda implied by have a 1-1 relation)